# Приведите пример создания нескольких ссылок на 1 объект

Tags: c#, объекты, ссылки

Могли бы вы описать пример, когда нам может потребоваться создать несколько ссылок на 1 объект? Ведь при объявлении нового экземпляра класса и приравниванию его к уже существующему тогоже класса, не произойдет полное копирование, а только создатся вторая ссылка на существующий объект. Это используют в реальной жизни? Можно же было бы просто добавить ошибку на этапе компиляции.

Comment: При передаче в метод в качестве аргумента, например. Внутри метода будет своя локальная ссылка.

Comment: Если вы попробуете написать любое приложение на c#, вам скорее всего понадобятся ссылки на консоль или на окно.

Comment: Это позволяет сильно экономить память и увеличивает произовдительность, так как большие объекты копировать не надо, просто передается ссылка. Так что используется повсеместно.

Answer (score 0):

Я понимаю вам тяжело в начале. Но вам нужно понять разницу между объектом тобеж экземпляром класса и ссылкой на него.

Примеров использования нескольких ссылок на один объект огромное количество, а причин на то множество: сортировка, поиск, массивы, списки ... Выделяя элемент из списка вы копируете ссылку.

Comment: Дополните какими-нибудь примерами кода, раз уж начали отвечать )